# How can I create a simple class that is similar to a datatable, but without the overhead?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, datatable

I want to create a simple class that is similar to a datatable, but without the overhead.

So loading the object with a sqldatareader, and then return this custom datatable-like object that will give me access to the rows and columns like:

```
myObject[rowID]["columnname"]
```

How would you go about creating such an object?

I don't want any built in methods/behavior for this object except for accessing the rows and columns of the data.

#### Update:

I don't want a datable, I want something much leaner (plus I want to learn how to create such an object).

Comment: a datatable is NOT a "database in object". It's just an xml representation of the data pulled back from a query, with some additional methods you can to manipulate that xml.  A recordset is the SAME thing (uses Xml under the hood).

Comment: The 'payload' your talking about is part of the code section, not data.  It's loaded exactly once, along with the rest of the .Net framework, whether you use it or not.  You MUST pay that price even if you never use a datatable at all.

Comment: Put another way: that part is just algorithms, expressed as code. _Code_ is cheap to load if you don't use it. And in the case of CLR libraries, you don't have a choice.  The whole CLR is always loaded.

Comment: -1 because this question is extremely ambiguous and unclear.

Comment: @Jole Coehoorn: a DataTable is not an XML representation of anything.  Other than that, I agree with you about overhead.  The question would be better asked as: "DataTables are too heavyweight for me because of X.  What are my alternatives?"

Answer (score 3):

This type of structure can be easily created with a type signature of:

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>>
```

This will allow access as you specify and should be pretty easy to populate.

You can always create an object that inherits from List < Dictionary < string, object > > and implements a constructor that takes a SqlDataReader. This constructor should create a enw dictionary for each row, and insert a new entry into the dictionary for each column, using the column name as the key.

Comment: do you know the default capicty for teh dictionary?

Comment: This is NOT lightwait, as a instance of the Dictionary is created for each row.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing something about how .Net works.  The extra overhead involved in a DataTable is not significant.  Can you point to a specific performance problem in existing code that you believe is caused by a datatable?  Perhaps we can help correct that in a more elegant way.

Comment: From what I understand a datatable is a database in object, so that must come with some overhead obviously which I don't need.  A custom implementation seems simple enough so why not?

Comment: No: a datatable is NOT an entire database in an object.

Comment: It does pull the entire query results into memory at once, though.  If that's where your problem is, what you want instead is a DataReader.  A DataReader will only load one row into memory at a time, and is VERY fast.

Comment: A datatable or dataset has allot of built in functionality, so the payload of the object will be much more than a streamlined version that I wanted.  i.e. you can perform SELECTS on a datatable, joins, have primary keys etc.

Comment: The 'payload' your talking about is hidden in the code section, and loaded as part of the .Net framework.  You MUST pay that price whether or not you choose to use a datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the specific thing you're asking about is how to use the convenient `["whatever"]` indexing syntax in your own table object.

If so, I suggest you refer to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) on indexers.

Answer (score 0):

`Dictionary<int,object[]>` would be better than `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`. You don't really need a dictionary for each row, since column names are the same for all rows. And if you want to have it lightweight, you should use column indexes instead of names.

So if you have a column "Name" that is a 3rd column, to get its value "Name" from a row ID 10, the code would be:

```
object val = table[10][2];
```

Another option is `SortedList<int,object[]>`... depending on the way you access the data (forward only or random access).

You could also use `MultiDictionary<int,object>` from [PowerCollections](http://www.codeplex.com/PowerCollections).

From the memory usage perspective, I think the best option would be to use a single dimension array with some slack capacity. So after each, say 100, rows, you would create a new array, copy the old contents to it and leave 100 empty rows at the end. But you would have to keep some sort of an index when you delete a row, so that it is marked as deleted without resizing the array.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't this a DataSet/DataTable? Maybe I didn't get the question.
Also, what is the programming language?